# For loop in python not running properly

Tags: for-loop, python-3.11

```
x=("hello. I am fine")
for i in x:
    if i==".":
       break
print(i)
```

Printing all strings before period (.)

Getting result (.) instead of Hello`your text`

Comment: Could you comment on what you think `i` is when the `break` statement is reached?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not entirely sure what you are trying to print however, I believe you want to print everything before the period. If so...

You need to indent the print statement. The if will break out of the loop when you hit the period. once you leave the loop then you have your print statement to print the last character (the .). Whereas when you put the print statement in the loop it will print all of the characters before the period.

```
x=("hello. I am fine")
for i in x:
    if i==".":
       break
    print(i)
```

However, if you are trying to print everything after the period you will need the following code.

This is a little bit more complicated. First, because we want to start at the period we need to find where the period is. Once we know that we can then print the characters starting from that point.

```
x=("hello. I am fine")
startPoint = x.index('.') # finds the index of the period

# loops through the index of the string from the period to the end
# We have the plus 1 to exclude the period from the print
for i in range(startPoint + 1, len(x)):

    # then print the index of the string (x[index])
    print(x[i], end="") # add the , end="" to print everything on the same line
```

I hope this helps.